# Book set in a near-future climate dystopia in which adults have been banished to deserts

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, dystopia

My sister saw a book available on Amazon recently, didn't buy it, and now has changed her mind and can't find it again. Hopefully someone here can help us.

It's a science fiction story set in a near future in which climate change has caused severe changes and adults have all been banished to live in harsh desert conditions; the rest of society is made up of young adults and children.

There's probably some redemptive arc built in to it as well.

Possibly the name or cover art relates to the word "Fall," but that's not a helpful search term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this ***[The Forcing](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/63232552-the-forcing)*** (2023) by Paul E. Hardisty...?

From a [review](https://geekdad.com/2023/02/the-forcing-by-paul-e-hardisty-a-book-review/):

> **In Canada and North America, as the habitable land mass shrinks, a drastic solution has been found to the problem of overcrowding. Everybody over a certain age, those considered responsible for the climate cataclysm, is forced to move to the arid wasteland that has become the southern USA.**
>
> David and his wife, May, are just the wrong side of the relocation age. Forced to pack up everything they own into a bag each, they join the queues and board the buses south. Here they are thrown in with a hodgepodge of characters from all walks of life. Their dignity is stripped by the impersonal system and their young guards who hold them in the utmost contempt. Effectively imprisoned in a gulag, David and May have to learn how to navigate their new life, and at the same time deal with the fractures in their marriage that are now laid bare. New friends and alliances are made as they try to survive the cataclysmic events that are coming their way.

[image: Front cover of "The Forcing" (2023) by Paul E. Hardisty.]

Comment: That looks like it fits the description I was given, as well as being recent enough it would plausibly have been promoted in her Amazon results. I'll relay the suggestion and see what my sister thinks.

Comment: Please come back and let us know!  If it is the answer, please accept it with the checkmark.  If not, maybe it would be possible to edit into the question some more details (where this suggestion doesn't match) to help identify the correct answer.

Comment: Takes a while to do the round-trip with messages, but this answer is now confirmed by my sister :-) Thanks!